# Coefficients of linear discriminants in the lda() function from package MASS in R

Tags: discriminant-analysis

I was reading Chapter 4 (LDA) of the book Introduction to Statistical learning with R (http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/ISLR%20Sixth%20Printing.pdf) and could not understand the "coefficients of linear discriminants" part in the output of the `lda()` function from the MASS package.

The example code is on page 161.
Specifically, my questions are:

1. How does function `lda()` choose the reference group? In the example, the $Y$ variable has 2 groups: "Up" and "Down". Is it that group "Down" would be automatically chosen as the reference group according to the alphabetical order?
2. I don't understand what the "coefficients of linear discriminants" are for and which group the "LD1" represents, "Down" or "Up": [image]

On page 143 of the book, discriminant function formula (4.19) has 3 terms:
[image]

So my guess is that the coefficients of linear discriminants themselves don't yield the $\delta_k(x)$ directly. So is there any command that can calculate the $\delta_k(x)$?

3. Why are there at most $K-1$ groups of coefficients of linear discriminants and what's the relationship between the coefficients among different groups?

Comment: Conamore, please take a tour of this site over tag [discriminant-analysis]. You will find answers (including mine) which explain your points: what are discriminant coefficients, what are Fisher's classification functions in LDA, how LDA is equivalent to canonical correlation analysis with k-1 dummies.

Comment: `I don't understand what the "coefficients of linear discriminants" are for and which group the "LD1" represents` LD1 is the discriminant function which discriminates the classes. The coefficients are the weights whereby the variables compose this function.